# How to disable back button in MasterDetailsView during display of Details pane only (when Master pane isn't visible)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

After adding a text view to my MasterDetailsView I noticed an anomaly of this item which can cause an inconvenience for users. In the interest of user experience (UX) and to prevent confusion to the user, is there a way to disable the back button on the Command Bar when the MasterDetailsView is showing the Detail pane only (and NOT showing the Master pane)? This would normally be when the window is snapped or less than a certain width + if both pane are showing, I then want the command bar back button to reappear

*Master pane (snapped/short window mode)*

[image: master pane]

*Details pane (snapped/short window mode)*

[image]

*XAML (MasterDetailsView page - loaded inside Frame within main page)*

```
<Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,20" Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtMDPageTitle" Text="Mail" x:FieldModifier="public" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtMDPageSubtitle" Text="name.surname@domain.com" x:FieldModifier="public" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <controls:MasterDetailsView
        x:Name="MyMasterDetailsView"
        Grid.Row="1"
        BackButtonBehavior="Automatic"
        CompactModeThresholdWidth="720"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Emails}"
        NoSelectionContent="Select an item to view" 
        SelectionChanged="MyMasterDetailsView_SelectionChanged">
        <controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,8">
                        <TextBlock 
                            Style="{ThemeResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" 
                            Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <TextBlock
                            Opacity=".6"
                            Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                            Text="{Binding Zone}" />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <Button
                        x:Name="MoreBtn"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="10"
                        Padding="10"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        Click="MoreBtn_Click"
                        Command="{Binding ElementName=RootGrid, Path=DataContext.OpenDialog}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                        Content="&#xE712;"
                        FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                        Visibility="{Binding ShowButton, Converter={StaticResource MyConveter}}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
        <controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock
                        Margin="12,-6,0,0"
                        Style="{ThemeResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}"
                        Text="{Binding From}"
                        />
                    <TextBlock
                        x:Name="Body"
                        Margin="0,12,0,0"
                        Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                        Text="{Binding Body}"
                        TextWrapping="Wrap"
                        />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate>
        <controls:MasterDetailsView.NoSelectionContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock
                        Margin="0,12"
                        FontSize="24"
                        Text="{Binding}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:MasterDetailsView.NoSelectionContentTemplate>
        <controls:MasterDetailsView.MasterCommandBar>
            <CommandBar>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Back" Label="Back" />
                <AppBarButton Icon="Forward" Label="Forward" />

                <CommandBar.Content>
                    <TextBlock Margin="12,14">
                        <Run Text="{Binding Emails.Count}" />
                        <Run Text="Items" />
                    </TextBlock>
                </CommandBar.Content>
            </CommandBar>
        </controls:MasterDetailsView.MasterCommandBar>
        <controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsCommandBar>
            <CommandBar>
                <AppBarButton Icon="MailReply" Label="Reply" />
                <AppBarButton Icon="MailReplyAll" Label="Reply All" />
                <AppBarButton Icon="MailForward" Label="Forward" />
            </CommandBar>
        </controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsCommandBar>
    </controls:MasterDetailsView>
</Grid>
```

*C# (MasterDetailsView page)*

```
    public sealed partial class MasterDetailPage : Page
    {
        public List<Email> Emails { get; set; }

        public MasterDetailPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;
            Emails = MyEmailManager.GetEmails();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            MainPage.Current.BackButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            MainPage.Current.BackButton.IsEnabled = true;
        }

        private void MyMasterDetailsView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

    public class Email
    {
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public bool ShowButton { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyEmailManager
    {
        public static List<Email> GetEmails()
        {
            var MyEmails = new List<Email>
        {
            new Email
            {
                From = "Steve Johnson",
                Body = "Are you available for lunch tomorrow? A client would like to discuss a project with you.",
                ShowButton = true
            },
            new Email
            {
                From = "Pete Davidson",
                Body = "Don't forget the kids have their soccer game this Friday. We have to supply end of game snacks.",
                ShowButton = false
            },
            new Email
            {
                From = "OneDrive",
                Body = "Your new album.\r\nYou uploaded some photos to your OneDrive and automatically created an album for you.",
                ShowButton = false
            },
            new Email
            {
                From = "Twitter",
                Body = "Here are some people we think you might like to follow:\r\n.@randomPerson\r\nAPersonYouMightKnow",
                ShowButton = true
            }
        };

            return MyEmails;
        }
    }

    public class CommadEventHandler<T> : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public Action<T> action;
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            this.action((T)parameter);
        }
        public CommadEventHandler(Action<T> action)
        {
            this.action = action;

        }
    }
}
```

*XAML (Main Page)*

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <CommandBar Grid.Row="0" DefaultLabelPosition="Right">
        <CommandBar.Content>
            <Button 
                x:FieldModifier="public"
                Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}" 
                Name="BackButton" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Click="Back_Click"/>
        </CommandBar.Content>
    </CommandBar>
    <Frame Name="MainFrame" Grid.Row="1" Padding="0"/>
</Grid>
```

*C# (MainPage)*

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Current = this;

        Frame_Main.Navigate(typeof(MsterDetailPage));
    }

    private void Back_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        On_BackRequested();
    }

    private bool On_BackRequested()
    {
        if (Frame_Main.CanGoBack)
        {
            Frame_Main.GoBack();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void BackInvoked(KeyboardAccelerator sender, KeyboardAcceleratorInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        On_BackRequested();
        args.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I noticed that you have two CommandBars and two BackButtons, one in MainPage and one in MasterDetailView. Do you mean that when the MasterDetailView is in the Detail state, the CommandBar of the MainPage is not displayed?

Comment: Hello. What I mean is when the MasterDetailView is in the Detail state, the CommandBar of the MainPage is still displayed, so I want to hide this.

Answer (score 0):

`MasterDetailView` provides ViewStateChanged event, which will be triggered when the display state of `MasterDetailView` changes. We can adjust the CommandBar in MainPage based on this event.

```cs
private void MyMasterDetailsView_ViewStateChanged(object sender, MasterDetailsViewState e)
{
    if (e == MasterDetailsViewState.Details)
    {
        MainPage.Current.BackButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        MainPage.Current.BackButton.IsEnabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        MainPage.Current.BackButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        MainPage.Current.BackButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```